# Weird for statement

Tags: java, for-loop

Today I've met strange form of for statement in some Java code:
Example of this statement is next:

```
String doSomething(){

  String str;

  for (str = ""; isTrue(); str = obj.findSomething(0)) {
    ;
  }

return str;
}
```

Finally, I didn't catch how it works.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Run it through a debugger while single-stepping and you'll see.

Comment: I don't see anything strange about it. May want to look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html if you thought for loops were only used for counters.

Comment: It works like a "normal" `for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)`. If you don't know what each part in a `for` statement mean, then read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String doSomething() {
    String str;
    for (str = ""; isTrue(); str = obj.findSomething(0)) {
        ; // inside
    }
    return str;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
String doSomething() {
    String str;
    { // begin of for loop's scope
        str = ""; // initialization
        while (isTrue()) { // termination
            {
                ; // inside
            }
            str = obj.findSomething(0); // increment
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This works for every for loop like this, an empty termination condition like in `for(;;)` is treated as `true`.

It's simply

```
String doSomething() {
    String str = "";
    while (isTrue()) {
        str = obj.findSomething(0);
    }
    return str;
}
```

and when written as such wouldn't be as confusing.